# Best way of track the order of entities stored in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I am creating this App which can display some contents in a collection view. The data source of the collection view is stored locally by using CoreData. Each collection view cell will have a corresponding CoreData entity. 
Since I am adding a "drag to reorder" feature to the collection view, I need some way to track the order of the CoreData entities. Anyone have any suggestions of how to achieve that?
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may add an integer property to your entity type. Every time you change the order of your entities you assign the current index to this property and save the context after that. You can fetch the entities sorted by this property to restore the order.

But this solution may have two problems:

1. It may be not performant for large entity sets, and/or frequent updates.
2. The entity order may not belong to the entity content. This can be problematic, for example, if the data is to be displayed in different views in different order.

In that case you should store the order not with the entities. Instead you can store the order in a property list, e.g. in an array with the identifiers of the entities.

Comment: I have tried the method of adding a integer attribute to the entity, and every time the order changed save the new index to the attribute. But there is a bug of this method that two different entities may have the same index num since they may have moved to the same location in the collection view. Your suggestion of creating a property list and save the identifiers in the list might work, I will try it out. Thank you for your response!

Comment: The most stable way should be enumerating all entities from start to end before saving, but this could be slow. Some optimizations would be possible, e.g.: Only renumbering the visible entities.